# How to expand calling expressions other than predicates?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees, linqkit

I just discovered LINQKit and am quite happy that it seems to provide a solution for the common problem of wanting to factor out parts of complex linq queries.

All examples, however, show how to factor out *predicates* for where-clauses.

Although that's a very typical use-case, I also want to factor out other kinds of expressions, typically for selects. Let's say I have the following sub-expression:

```
    Expression<Func<SomeFunkyEntity, String>> GetStatusFromSomeFunkyEntity()
    {
        return i =>
            i.IsExercise ? "Excercise" :
            i.IsExpired ? "Expired" :
            (i.IsLocked ) ? "Locked" :
            i.IsAdmitted ? "Admissible" : "Unusable";
    }
```

Does LINQKit provide a way to expand a call to this? I tried:

```
var query =
    from i in this.DbContext.MyFunkyEntities.AsExpandable()
    select new SomeFunkyEntityWithStatus()
    {
        FunkyEntity = i,
        Status = GetStatusFromSomeFunkyEntity().Invoke(i)
    };
```

This complies, but fails at runtime in LINQKit's expander:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.
```

The stack trace starts with:

```
at LinqKit.ExpressionExpander.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
at LinqKit.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
at LinqKit.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment assignment)
...
```

Is this not supported, or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to assign the expression to a local variable before calling invoke?

```
var statusFromSomeFunkyEntity = GetStatusFromSomeFunkyEntity();

var query =
    from i in this.DbContext.MyFunkyEntities.AsExpandable()
    select new SomeFunkyEntityWithStatus()
    {
        FunkyEntity = i,
        Status = statusFromSomeFunkyEntity.Invoke(i)
    };
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686682/3208242).

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! Indeed another case of that other issue I remember having read, but apparently not internalized properly.